# Functional-style list in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I've implemented a functional-style list structure in C++. It seems okay so far, and doing custom allocation for list nodes improves performance greatly. I omitted that part here for simplicity.

The mutability of the list is intentional, as the application I'm thinking of requires a lot of state updates. I wrote this code instead of using `std::forward_list` because

1. I need to instantiate the list with incomplete types.
2. The algorithm is recursive (some kind of tree search), so the code will look better with a functional data structure.

Any advice is welcome.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct List
{
    T head;
    std::unique_ptr<List<T>> tail;
};

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> add(const T &t, std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &&l)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<List<T>>(new List<T>{t, std::move(l)});
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> list()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<List<T>>();
}

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> list(const T &t, const Ts &...ts)
{
    return add(t, list<T>(ts...));
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> copy(const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &l)
{
    if (l == list<T>())
    {
        return list<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return add(l->head, copy(l->tail));
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> merge(const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &a, const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &b)
{
    if (a == list<T>())
    {
        return copy(b);
    }
    else
    {
        return add(a->head, merge(a->tail, b));
    }
}

template<typename T, typename Filter>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> filter(const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &l, Filter f)
{
    if (l == list<T>())
    {
        return list<T>();
    }
    else if (f(l->head))
    {
        return add(l->head, filter(l->tail, f));
    }
    else
    {
        return filter(l->tail, f);
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<List<T>> sort(const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &l)
{
    if (l == list<T>())
    {
        return list<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return merge(sort(filter(l->tail, [&](const T &t){return t < l->head;})), add(l->head, sort(filter(l->tail, [&](const T &t){return t >= l->head;}))));
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::unique_ptr<List<T>> &l)
{
    if (l == list<T>())
    {
        return os;
    }
    else
    {
        return os << l->head << ' ' << l->tail;
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<List<int>> randomList(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return list<int>();
    }
    else
    {
        return add(std::rand() % 100, randomList(n - 1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto r = randomList(100);
    std::cout << r << '\n' << sort(r) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks pretty solid. I don't have any major comments. Just lots of minor ones.

---

**Unique or Shared**

Why `unique_ptr` as a design choice over `shared_ptr`? The latter would let you be able to take shallow copies to your lists without having to have references everywhere. I'm not saying that `shared_ptr` is strictly better, more than it's something worth considering if you have not already. Either way, both are strictly better than raw pointers, so you're already on the right track.

**`std::unique_ptr<List<T>>`**

That is a huge mouthful to type every time. And it is the only type that matters. So let's just alias it:

```
template <typename T>
using FList = std::unique_ptr<List<T>>;
```

Alternatively, rename `List<>` to `Cons` or `Node` so that the alias can be named `List`. To avoid confusion, I will use `FList` throughout the rest of this review.

**`cons()`**

The standard name for a list structure that is a value and a list is a "cons" cell. As in **cons**truct. Just for consistency, you should rename your `add()` to `cons()`:

```
template<typename T>
FList<T> cons(const T& t, FList<T>&& xs)
{
    return {new List<T>{t, std::move(xs)}};
}
```

Now, this is less usable than it could be, simply because you can't do something like:

```
FList<long> x = ...;
cons(4, std::move(x)); // error
```

For that, let's loosen the restrictions:

```
template <typename T,
          typename U,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, U&&>::value>
          >
FList<T> cons(U&& u, FList<T>&& xs)
{
    return {new List<T>{std::forward<U>(u), std::move(xs)}};
}
```

You'll note that I changed your variable from `l` to `xs`. `1` is a terrible variable name as it's very easy to mistake for `l`. So easy to mistake that you probably didn't notice that I wrote one the first time and el the second time.

**`list()`**

Going on the theme of loosening restrictions, let's do that here too:

```
template<typename T>
FList<T> list()
{
    return {}; // shorter
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename...Us>
FList<T> list(U&& u, Us&&... us)
{
    return cons(std::forward<U>(u), 
                list<T>(std::forward<Us>(us)...)
                );
}
```

That will let you write:

```
auto nums = list<int>(1, '4', 5ull);
```

**Checking for empty list**

In your functions, you tend to start with:

```
if (l == list<T>())
```

But `std::unique_ptr` is usable in a boolean context as-is. So all of those checks you can write much simpler:

```
template<typename T>
FList<T> copy(const FList<T>& xs)
{
    if (!xs)
    {
        return {};
    }
    else
    {
        return cons(xs->head, copy(xs->tail));
    }
}
```

Note that in the interest of being functional, we also probably want:

```
template <typename T>
T const& car(FList<T> const& xs) { // or T& if you want mutability
    return xs->head;
}

template <typename T>
FList<T> const& cdr(FList<T> const& xs) { 
    return xs->tail;
}
```

So that this becomes:

```
return cons(car(xs), copy(cdr(xs)));
```

**`filter()`**

Could avoid some code duplication here:

```
template<typename T, typename Filter>
FList<T> filter(const FList<T>& xs, Filter f)
{
    if (!xs) {
        return {};
    }

    auto tail = filter(cdr(xs), f);
    return f(car(xs)) 
           ? cons(car(xs), std::move(tail)) 
           : tail;
}
```

**`sort()`**

This function deserves a comment solely for:

```
    return merge(sort(filter(l->tail, [&](const T &t){return t < l->head;})), add(l->head, sort(filter(l->tail, [&](const T &t){return t >= l->head;}))));
```

It's like you never want anybody to read your code. So you're basically trying to do a sort of quicksort based on partitioning the head. Let's just write that in more than one line of code (and rename it to `sorted` to mimic python and make it sound less like you're sorting in place):

```
template<typename T>
FList<T> sorted(const FList<T>& xs)
{
    if (!xs) return {};

    auto left = filter(cdr(xs), [&](const T& val){ return val < car(xs); });
    auto right = filter(cdr(xs), [&](const T& val){ return !(val < car(xs)); });

    return merge(sorted(left), 
                 cons(car(xs), sorted(right)));
}
```

I find that a ton easier to read. The reason I wrote the second filter with `!` is that it naturally lends itself to adding a custom comparator:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T>>
FList<T> sorted(const FList<T>& xs, Cmp cmp = {})
{
    if (!xs) return {};

    auto left = filter(cdr(xs), [&](const T& val){ return cmp(val, car(xs)); });
    auto right = filter(cdr(xs), [&](const T& val){ return !cmp(val, car(xs)); });

    return merge(sorted(left, cmp), 
                 cons(car(xs), sorted(right, cmp)));
}
```